# Batch upsert query for batch update in Apache Phoenix

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am currently using following query for batch update on  Phoenix. Is there any other way to do it better? It takes 0.071 seconds to execute.

Take a look at following working query:
Consider a table XYZ with columns ID,CF.RISK;

`UPSERT INTO XYZ (
    ID,
    CF.RISK
    SELECT ID,
        (CASE ID
            WHEN '12341e65-a68b-4f88-93ce-33dd94497a6d' THEN 'MEDIUM_RISK'
            WHEN '73f41e65-a68b-4f88-93ce-33dd94497a6d' THEN 'HIGH_RISK'
            ELSE 'LOW_RISK'
        END)
      FROM ACCOUNTS
        WHERE ID IN(
                '12341e65-a68b-4f88-93ce-33dd94497a6d',
                '73f41e65-a68b-4f88-93ce-33dd94497a6d')`

It updates column CF.RISK for all ID's in WHERE clause list.

Comment: Is it always two ids, or you want to have a longer list? If it is only two, you can execute two queries, maybe it is faster. If it is a long list of ids you may want to define a new table where you have the mapping of ids and their risks. Then do a join

Comment: No it can be 'n' number of ids. And i dont think using join is worth it if phoenix provides us with CASE queries. Neither we need to create new table.That will be an overhead